# strncpy_s - buffer is too small assertation

Tags: c++, strncpy

As part of a small program i need to convert a string to a char array. I want to use the strncpy_s() method but I keep getting an assertation saying that the "buffer is too small". 
This is what my code looks like:

```
char* ostr = new char[sizeof(str)+1];
strncpy_s(ostr, sizeof(ostr), str.c_str(), sizeof(ostr));
```

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: this is probably an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you need to manipulate the string, do that **as** a `std::string`, if you need to pass a `char*` to a c-style function, use the member `c_str()`

Answer (score 3):

The variable `str` is, it seems, a `std::string` object. The size of the object is the size of its member variables, which for `std::string` commonly is a pointer (to the actual string) and variable for the length of the string.

If you want to get the length of the wrapped string you need to use the [`length`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) function.

Furthermore, there is another problem with your call to `strncpy_s`: You do `sizeof(ostr)`, which is the size *of the pointer*, not the size of the memory it points to.

---

Lastly, if you want to pass a pointer to the string to a C function, then either use `str.c_str()` directly in the call. Or if the C function needs to modify the string (but not reallocate it) then use e.g. `str.data()` or `&str[0]`.

If the C function needs to reallocate the data then you can't use `new[]` to allocate it. You need to use `malloc` (or possibly `strdup` if your system have it).